# What is a finite partial function from $\mathfrak c$ to $D=\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, notation, terminology, definition

While I reading a paper, there is a notation is called finite partial function. I searched by google, I cannot find its definition. So I post it here as a question:

> What is a finite partial function from $\mathfrak c$ to $D=\{0,1\}$?

Thanks!

Comment: It might help if you tell us what c is?

Comment: $\mathfrak c$ is the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: It denotes the continuum, i.e., $2^\omega$.

Comment: It is a function with range contained in $D$, and domain a finite subset of $\mathfrak c$. In general, a partial function from $A$ to $B$ is a function $f$ with domain some subset of $A$ and range (contained in) $B$. If the domain of $f$ is $A$, one says that $f$ is a *total* function.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thanks.

Comment: Even if you stumbled upon this in a paper from the area of ([tag:general-topology]), I guess ([tag:set-theory]) might be a more suitable tag. I believe it is always good to provide the context for the question - in this case it would be the name and citation for the paper you are reading and a link to the paper (if it is available online).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the comment as an answer:

It is a function with range contained in $D$, and domain a finite subset of $\mathfrak c$. In general, a partial function from $A$ to $B$ is a function $f$ with domain some subset of $A$ and range (contained in) $B$. If the domain of $f$ is $A$, one says that $f$ is a *total* function.

I believe it was [Adrian Mathias](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/) who introduced the notation $f\mathrel{\vdots}A\to B$ to indicate that $f$ is a partial function from $A$ to $B$. In computability theory, one sees the notation $f(x)\downarrow$ to indicate that $x\in\mathrm{dom}(f)$, and $f(x)\uparrow$ to indicate otherwise. The idea is that one thinks of $f$ as a program performing a computation with input $x$. The downarrow indicates that the computation *converges*, and the uparrow, that it *diverges*.

In set theory, in the context of forcing, it is common to talk of partial functions. Given a poset of partial functions, typically, the *generic* object $G$ one obtains gives us a total function, obtained by pasting together the partial approximations in $G$.